# section is not responding to CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've started coding this landing page and after I was done with the fullvp menu the section class="hero" is now not responding, when trying to edit it on chrome it actually worked. so, I went back to my source to see if there are any typos or missing symbols - didn't find none -_-, so... Need some help from the community, thank
P.S 
It's probably something stupid I've done so my apologies =)

```css
img { width: 100%; }

header {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#logo {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}


#menu-icon {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
  transition: .3s ease;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu-icon:hover, #menu-icon:focus {
  /*background: black;*/
  transition: .5s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color:royalblue;
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }

  .hero {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding: 1px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Student Loan Landing Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="norm.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <section class="header">
      <header> 
        <h1 id="logo">SAVVY STUDENT</h1>
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span id="menu-icon" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
       </header>
    </section>
    <section class="hero">
      <div class="hero-content">
        <h2 id="hero-content-headline">GRADUATE FROM STUDENT LOANS</h2>
        <p id="hero-content-content">STUDENT LOAN DEBT, RECORD BREAKING $1.5 TRILIAN.  POST STUDENTS ARE TAKING ADVANTAGE OF DEBT RELIEFE.  WE BELIVE THAT EVERYONE DESERVES A SECOND CHANGE. DON’T FALL BEGIND TAKE ADVANTAGE OF STUDENT LOAN FORGIVENESS.  APPLY NOW AND FIND OUT HOW MUCH YOU CAN GET FORGIVEN</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-wrap">
        <form method="post" action="send.php">
          <legend>Find out how much you can get forgiven <span class="form-tagline">Enter your details and we will get in touch</span></legend>
          <fieldset class="form-fields">
            <label for="user-first">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_first_name" class="user-first">
            <label for="user-last">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_last_name" class="user-last"><br>
            <label for="user-email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email_address" class="user-email">
            <label for="user-phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" name="user_phone_number" class="user-phone"><br>
            <label for="user-address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_address_street" class="user-address">
            <label for="user-city">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_address_city" class="user-acity"><br>
            <label for="user-state">State</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_address_state" class="user-state">
            <label for="user-zip">Zip</label>
            <input type="number" name="user_address_zip" class="user-zip"><br>
            <button type="submit">find out now!</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="why-program">
      <div class="why-program-wrap">
        <h1>Why Apply to Student Loan Forgiveness Program?</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><span><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Reduce payment</li>
          <li><span><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Consolidate loans</li>
          <li><span><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Increase credit Score</li>
          <li><span><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Deal with one lender</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="features">
      <div class="feature-apply feeature">
        <span><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <h3>Apply today</h3>
        <p>Fill out the form or give us a call.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-apply feeature">
        <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <h3>Approved</h3>
        <p>Submit your request with 1 of our consultants and get approved in minutes.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-apply feeature">
        <span><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <h3>Enroll</h3>
        <p>To one of the programs and change your life today</p>
      </div>
      <div class="features-video">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BeBx8UdVOCc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="reviews">
      <h3>What Are Clients Say...</h3>
      <div class="review">
        <img src="" alt="Reviewer-name" class="reviewer-photo">
        <h3 class="review-name">Bob Smith</h3>
        <p class="review-content">Best Company Ever</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="how-works">
      <div class="how how-1">
        <h3>one stop shop</h3>
        <p>We do it all for you from preparing your documentation, talking to your lender, enrolling you to the program, you don’t need to lift a finger.</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="how how-2">
        <h3>You are safe</h3>
        <p>We are a trusted company with your information encrypted to our system where only the Department of Education has access too.</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="how how-3">
        <h3>Approved in 1 call</h3>
        <p>In just 1 phone call our team of experts will let you know if you get approved.</p>
      </div> 
    </section>
    <section class="why-us">
      <h3>Why Us</h3>
      <p>[company] main priority is to help post students get the financial aid they deserve. Company has been in business for years. Professionally providing great customer service with 1 point of contact and quick response. While keeping your personal information safe and secured. Our team of consultants and underwriters strive on providing on point information on enrolling you to the program that will best benefit you. We stick by you on the full length of your program, providing you with answers to all your questions and concerns.</p>
    </section>
    <div class="divider"><hr></div>
    <section class="articles">
      <div class="article">
        <img class="article-img" alt="" src="RES/HERO-2.jpg">
        <h3 class="article-head">Lorem Ipsum has been</h3>
        <p class="article-content">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</p>
        <a href="" class="article-button">read more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
        <img class="article-img" alt="" src="RES/HERO-2.jpg">
        <h3 class="article-head">Lorem Ipsum has been</h3>
        <p class="article-content">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</p>
        <a href="" class="article-button">read more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
        <img class="article-img" alt="" src="RES/HERO-2.jpg">
        <h3 class="article-head">Lorem Ipsum has been</h3>
        <p class="article-content">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</p>
        <a href="" class="article-button">read more</a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
    <section class="contact-us">
      <div class="colm-1">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Office: (866) 210-1337</li>
          <li>Address: 2351 W 3rd St<br>Los Angeles, CA</li>
          <li>Email: info@fslforgive.com</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="colm-2">
        <form method="post" action="send.php">
          <legend>Find out how much you can get forgiven <span class="form-tagline">Enter your details and we will get in touch</span></legend>
          <fieldset class="form-fields">
            <label for="user-first">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_first_name" class="user-first">
            <label for="user-last">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_last_name" class="user-last"><br>
            <label for="user-email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email_address" class="user-email">
            <label for="user-phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" name="user_phone_number" class="user-phone"><br>
            <label for="user-address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_address_street" class="user-address">
            <label for="user-city">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_address_city" class="user-acity"><br>
            <label for="user-state">State</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_address_state" class="user-state">
            <label for="user-zip">Zip</label>
            <input type="number" name="user_address_zip" class="user-zip"><br>
            <button type="submit">find out now!</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <span><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </div>
    </section>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e4028997c7.js"></script>
  <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you run your HTML through a validator yet to look for syntax errors?

Comment: What does "not responding to CSS" mean?  Is there a specific element which should have a specific style rule but doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@media screen is not closed properly

```
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}/**closing bracket is missing***/

 .hero {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding: 1px;
  }
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xORWmd

Comment: problem is you enclosed the .hero class  inside @media screen and it takes into effect , if the screensize is less than 450px